# Angular and Node: JWT authentication when accessing directly with a URL to a secret route

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, jwt, passport.js

In my project I'm using Angular 5, nodejs, JWT to sign tokens and passport.js to manage the authentication (token decode). On the backend side, the authentication works well when I use an Angular Interceptor which automatically set an header when intercept an http request.

**Assuming I'm accessing /user/profile, which is my protected route in node, if I directly type the protected route (full url http://localhost:3000/user/profile) in the browser how can I manage to grant an already authenticated user to access that page instead of an Unathorized message from passport.js which of course can't see any token in header (body, query neither)?**

The only way I managed it was creating this route:

```
router.get('/isauthenticated', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), function (req, res) {
res.json({
    id: req.user.id,
    email: req.user.email
});
});
```

and call it in "ngOnInit" in ProfileComponent. If /isauthenticated goes well, then I let user visit Profile page.
I think this solution is a workaround and definitely not elegant... so my question is, apart from using or not passport.js:

**is it possible to use JWT authentication with Angular and protect a route with nodejs and then let an already authenticated user (which has a token which isn't expired of course) to enter the protected route even if he directly type the URL in the browser?**

Please tell me even if you use something else isntead of passport.js or if I have to use another strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the jwt token inside of the local storage of the browser. Then you can check whether that token is expired or not by using a method called "tokenNotExpired()".
The authentication service should change like this.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  registerUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('https://herokuapp.com/users/register', user,{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  authenticateUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('https://herokuapp.com/users/authenticate', user,{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getProfile(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('https://herokuapp.com/users/profile',{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  storeUserData(token, user){
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  loadToken(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }

  loadUser(){
    const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired();  //Expired => return false
  }

  logout(){
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

And the login.component.ts should be change like this

```js
onLoginSubmit() {
    const user = {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    }
    
     
    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.success) {
        this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);
        this.router.navigate(['/pages/dashboard']);
      } else {
        swal(
          'Oops...',
          'Invalid Email or Password..!',
          'error'
        )
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        this.password = '';
      }
    });
}
```

Then you can add this ngOnInit() method to any component.ts file. If the token is stored in the local storage,then you can go to that page without any problem.And also you can go to any page by typing url like this. (http://localhost:3000/user/profile)

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.loadToken();
    if(!localStorage.getItem('id_token')){
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);  
    }
}
```